# How to understand Chegireddy-Hamacher's algorithm for finding k-best perfect matching

Tags: matching-theory, perfect-matchings

I am reading [Algorithms for finding K-best perfect matchings](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82129717.pdf) by Chegireddy and Hamacher, and I have trouble to understand their Section 2 "General algorithm for K-best perfect matchings ". Particularly, I am confused by their notations $I_k$, $I_p$, $O_k$, and $O_p$, and not sure how to construct these sets iteratively. I tried to work out an example, but stuck at the 4th matching, see below.

Suppose we have found the 1st and 2nd maximum weight matchings for the graph $G$, denoted as $M_1$ and $M_2$ respectively. To find the the 3rd matching, let $e\in M_1-M_2$, which is an edge in the matching $M_1$ but not $M_2$. With that, we consider two graphs: $G_1$, which is obtained by removing, from $G$, the two nodes of $e$ and their incident edges, and $G_2$, which is obtained by setting the weight of $e$ to $-\infty$.

Now the 1st maximum weight matching for $G_1$ is $M_1$, and we can find its 2nd maximum weight matching, denoted as $M_3^{(1)}$. Similarly, the 1st maximum weight matching for $G_2$ is $M_2$, and we can find its 2nd maximum weight matching, denoted as $M_3^{(2)}$. From $M_3^{(1)}$ and $M_3^{(2)}$, the one with largest weight is the 3rd best matching $M_3$ because $M_3$ either contain or not contain the edge $e$.

Now how should I proceed to find the 4th matching? I am thinking to repeat the above process by replacing $(G, M_1, M_2)$ with $(G_1, M_1, M_3^{(1)})$ and $(G_2, M_2, M_3^{(2)})$ respectively. Then in total, there are 4 subproblems for the 4th matching, and it seems to lead to an exponential-time algorithm, instead of polynomial-time, as claimed in the paper. In particular, this is in contrast to the 2 subproblems in each iteration of their "K-Best Matching Algorithm (AKM)", see the Step 4 of the algorithm. So I must have missed something, and what is that? Thank you!

Comment: To my question above: do we need to repeat the process for $(G_1, M_1, M_3^{(1)})$ **and** $(G_2, M_2, M_3^{(2)})$ in order to find the 4th best matching? The answer is no, and if we assume $M_3^{(1)}$ has larger weight than $M_3^{(2)}$, then we only need to repeat the process for $(G_1, M_1, M_3^{(1)})$. To see that, let's use $M_4^{(1, 2)}$ to denote the results of repeating the process. Now $M_4^{(2)}$ necessarily has smaller weight than $M_3^{(2)}$, hence $M_4^{(2)}$ can't be the 4th best matching. But we still need to compare $M_3^{(2)}$ to $M_4^{(1)}$ to find the one with larger weight.

Answer (score 0):

Below I will post the Chegireddy-Hamacher algorithm I understood. For my purpose, best matching means minimum weight perfect matching (MWPM) below. This, and some notations below, is different from the post above and the original paper.

**K=1**: This is essentially finding the MWPM for a graph, which can be done with the standard [Blossom algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm). Let's denote the result as $M_1\equiv\text{MWPM}(G)$, and its weight is denoted as $w(M_1)$.

**K=2**: This is to find the 2nd MWPM $M_2$, with weight $w(M_2)>w(M_1)$, and $w(M_2)<w(M')$ for all other matchings $M'$. This can be done with the "Second Best Matching Algorithm" in the paper, which can be written as a recursive algorithm

```
function SecondMWPM(G, M_1) 
# Finding 2nd MWPM M_2 for a given graph G(V, E) and MWPM M_1

if M_1 is empty
   return M_1
end

# Let e be an edge in M_1. There are two possibilities 
# Possibility 1: e is also in M_2

Define G', obtained by removing the two vertices v_1, and v_2 of e, and their incident edges, from G

Define M_1', obtained by removing the edge e from M_1

M_2' = SecondMWPM(G', M_1') 

Put the edge e back to M_2' [first candidate of 2nd MWPM]

# Possibility 2: e is not in M_2

Define G'', obtained by removing the edge e, from G

M_2''= MWPM(G'') [2nd candidate of 2nd MWPM]

return M_2' or M_2'', which ever has the lower weight

end
```

This is different from the algorithm presented in the paper, but the idea is the same, namely that $M_2$ either share or not share a particular edge $e\in M_1$. If $e\in M_2$, then by removing the two vertices $v_1, v_2\in e$ and their incident edges [which of course contains e] from $M_1$, $M_2$ and $G$, $M_2$ is still the 2nd MWPM of the reduced graph, hence renders a recursive algorithm. If $e\notin M_2$, then by removing $e$ from $G$ [while retain its vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$], $M_2$ is the MWPM of the reduced graph. With these two candidates obtained, we simply compare which one has the lower weight.

$\text{SecondMWPM}(G, M_1)$ will be used to find the subsequent MWPMs.

**K>=3**: The algorithm can be written as follows

```
bank = [] # Bank of candidates for the next MWPM, which is a list of Tuple of 3 elements, see below

Gp = G # The original graph
Mp1 = M_1 # MWPM found above
Mp2 = M_2 # 2nd MWPM found above

MWPMs = [M_1, M_2] # The list of K MWPMs

for k in [3, 4, ..., K]

Define e such that e is in Mp1, but not Mp2

Define G', obtained by removing the two vertices v_1, and v_2 of e, and their incident edges, from Gp

Define G'', obtained by removing the edge e from Gp

Mp3 = SecondMWPM(G', Mp1) # Mp1 is the MWPM of G'

# Put Mp3 into the bank as a candidate. 
push!(bank, (G', Mp1, Mp3))

Mp4 = SecondMWPM(G'', Mp2) # Mp2 is the MWPM of G''

# Put Mp4 into the bank as a candidate. 
push!(bank, (G'', Mp2, Mp4))

# From the bank, find which tuple, its 3rd element has the smallest weight

ind = find_which_tuple_has_min_weight_for_3rd_element(bank)

# That is the k-th MWPM
push!(MWPMs, bank[ind][3])

# The associated tuple is the starting point of finding the next MWPM
Gp = bank[ind][1]
Mp1 = bank[ind][2]
Mp2 = bank[ind][3]


# Remove it from the bank
delete bank[ind]


end
```

When $K=3$, this algorithm reduces to that I described above for finding the 3rd MWPM, and it is in fact the bulk of the for loop. For each iteration of $K\geq k>3$, we only need to call twice the function $\text{SecondMWPM}$, and compare the result to all previous found candidates in the "bank". A few remarks

1. Each tuple in the "bank" has three elements, so that we have all the information (reduced graph and its first two MWPMs) needed to find the subsequent MWPMs. In particular, let's denote $(G_j, M_j^{(1)}, M_j^{(2)})\in\text{bank}$, where $M_j^{(1)}, M_j^{(2)}$ are the 1st and 2nd MWPM for the reduced graph $G_j$.
2. This "bank" plays the roles of the sets $I_p$ and $O_p$ defined in the paper, which, however, I find very hard to understand.
3. In the actual implementation, keeping the "bank" won't be memory efficient. It is included here for the ease of understanding.
4. Suppose $M_{j=1}^{(2)}$ has the smallest weight compared to all other $M_{j>1}^{(2)}$, i.e. $w(M_{1}^{(2)})<w(M_{j}^{(2)})$ for $\forall j> 1$, then it is the k-th MWPM we are after.
5. To find the $k+1$-th MWPM, we simply find the 3rd MWPM for $G_1$ with the information in $(G_{j=1}, M_{j=1}^{(1)}, M_{j=1}^{(2)})\in\text{bank}$, and compare with $M_{j>1}^{(2)}$ to determine the $k+1$-th MWPM.
6. To see that, let's also denote $M_j^{(3)}$ as the 3rd MWPM for the reduced graph $G_j$ which are unknown yet. By definition $M_{j}^{(3)}>M_{j}^{(2)}$. Hence there is no need find $M_{j>1}^{(3)}$, because $M_{j>1}^{(2)}$ would be better candidate for the $k+1$-th MWPM. On the other hand, we do need to find $M_{1}^{(3)}$ and compare with $M_{j>1}^{(2)}$ because a priori, we don't know whether $M_{j>1}^{(2)}$ or $M_{j=1}^{(3)}$ has the smallest weight.